# 'Client' object has no attribute 'authorize' in gcp.How to solve this?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, disk, google-apis-explorer, oauth2client

I'm deleting disks in GKE cluster.I'm using my JSON-key credentials to delete the disk associated with a specific cluster.

**Python**

```
from google.cloud import storage
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("json_key")
service = discovery.build('compute','v1',credentials=credentials)
project = #PROJECT-NAME#
zone = #ZONE-NAME#
disk = [#list of disks]
for i in disk:
    request = service.disks().delete(project=project, zone=zone, disk=disk)
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
```

While executing I'm facing an error **'Client' object has no attribute 'authorize'**.Where I'm going wrong here?

How to delete the disks for a specific cluster.Is ther any other way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the whole traceback please?

Comment: Most likely this line failed `credentials = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("json_key")`.  Replace `json_key` with the filename of the service account JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storage you can try with `ServiceAccountCredentials` by following the [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/service_account/tasks.py) and try below sample:

```
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      'key.json',
      scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```